# Linux - check when crontab file was last amended

Tags: linux, crontab

How can i get the last updated date/time of the crontab file.  not when cron was last run but instead when was the crontab file amended last

Answer (score 17):

If you are root or sudoer:

```
sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER
```

UPD: as pointed by @jgr, the exact path may vary, like:

```
sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/$USER
```

Otherwise, it doesn't seem to be possible without altering directory permissions.

Comment: On fedora users crontabs are stored in `/var/spool/cron/$USER`, the above looks like solaris or something :/

Comment: On my Ubuntu, the first path is OK.

Comment: /var/spool/cron/tabs/$USER worked for me